# WSAEFAULT 10014, Why setsockopt returning -1?

Tags: windows, sockets, pointers

My `setsockopt()` call is returning -1, I used `WSAGetLastError()` which returns `WSAEFAULT`.

> WSAEFAULT
> 10014
> Bad address.
>
> The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument of a call. This error occurs if an application passes an invalid pointer value, or if the length of the buffer is too small. For instance, if the length of an argument, which is a sockaddr structure, is smaller than the sizeof(sockaddr).

I am using MSVC 2022

```
#include<iostream>
#include<WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;
#define PORT 9909

struct sockaddr_in srv;
fd_set fr, fw, fe;
int nMaxFd;

int main() {

    int nRet = 0;

    // Initialize the WSA variables
    WSADATA ws;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &ws) < 0) {
        cout << endl << "WSA failed to initialize";
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    else 
        cout << endl << "WSA initialized";

    // Initialize the socket
    int nSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (nSocket < 0) {
        cout << endl << "The socket not opened";
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        cout << endl << "The socket opened successfully"<<nSocket;
    }

    // Initialize the environment for sockaddr structure
    srv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srv.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    srv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    memset(srv.sin_zero, 0, 8);

    // setsockpot
    
    int nOptVal = 1;
    int nOptLen = sizeof(nOptVal);
    nRet = setsockopt(nSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)nOptVal, nOptLen);
    cout << nRet;
    if (!nRet) {
        cout << endl << "The setsockopt call successful";
    }
    else {
        cout << endl << "THe setsockopt call failed";
        cout << endl << WSAGetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    /* In default, every socket is Blocking socket, we have to use explicitly if wer want non blocking sockets
    // About the Blocking and Non Blocking sockets
    u_long optval = 0;
    nRet = ioctlsocket(nSocket, FIONBIO, &optval);
    if (nRet != 0) {
        cout << endl << "ioctlsocket call failed";
    }
    else {
        cout << endl << "ioctlsocket call passed";
    }
    */

    /*
    // Bind the socket to the local port
    nRet = bind(nSocket, (sockaddr*)&srv, sizeof(sockaddr));
    if (nRet < 0) {
        cout << endl << "Fail to bind to local port";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        cout << endl << "Successfully bind to local port";

    // Listen the request from client (queues the requests)
    nRet = listen(nSocket, 5);
    if (nRet < 0) {
        cout << endl << "Fail to start listen to local port";
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        cout << endl << "Started listening to local port";
    }
    nMaxFd = nSocket;
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    while (1) {
        FD_ZERO(&fr);
        FD_ZERO(&fw);
        FD_ZERO(&fe);

        FD_SET(nSocket, &fr);
        FD_SET(nSocket, &fe);

        cout << endl << "Before select call: " << fr.fd_count;
        // Keep waiting for new requests and proceed as per the request
        nRet = select(nMaxFd + 1, &fr, &fw, &fe, &tv);
        if (nRet > 0) {
            // When someone connects or communicates with a message over a dedicated connection
        }
        else if (nRet == 0) {
            // No connection or any communication request made or you can say that none of the 
            // socket descriptors are ready
            cout << endl << "Nothing on port: " << PORT;
        }
        else {
            // It failed and your application should show some useful message
            cout << endl << "I failed...";
            WSACleanup();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cout << endl << "After the select call: " << fr.fd_count;
    }

    */
}
```

[image: Output]

I assumed my `setsockopt()` will return 0, but it returns -1:

```
int nOptVal = 1;
int nOptLen = sizeof(nOptVal);
nRet = setsockopt(nSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)nOptVal, nOptLen);
```

Answer (score -1):

Per the [`setsockopt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-setsockopt) documentation,  the `WSAEFAULT` error is telling you that you are passing in an invalid pointer in the `optval` parameter:

> | Error code | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | WSAEFAULT | **The buffer pointed to by the `optval` parameter is not in a valid part of the process address space** or the `optlen` parameter is too small. |

When calling `setsockopt()`, you need to pass in the *memory address* of the `nOptVal` variable, but you are passing in its *value* instead, typecasted to a pointer. `1` is not a valid memory address of the variable, hence the error.

Try this instead:

```
int nOptVal = 1;
int nOptLen = sizeof(nOptVal);
nRet = setsockopt(nSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&nOptVal, nOptLen);
                                                                  ^
                                                               add this!
```